# Identify Attribute of Each Object in Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to identify an attribute within each object of an array of checked boxes, but this code returns the desired element of only the attribute of the first object in the array for the number of boxes that I have checked. Here is my code:

```
function() {
    var checkedBoxes = $("[name='select-services']:checked");
    checkedBoxes.each(function(){
        console.log(checkedBoxes.attr("value"))
    }
```

For example, if the values of three selected boxes are "value 1", "value 2", and "value 3", I will receive the output "value 1" three times.

Comment: Refer to `this` inside the `each` to get to the item being iterated over. (or use the second argument)

Answer (score 1):

Like the description of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) says:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

What you're doing now is getting the `attr` of the first item in `checkedBoxes`. But what you want is to get the value of the item you're currently iterating over. You can do that using `$(this)` in the function like in the example below.

```
checkedBoxes.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("value"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code assigns an `obj` reference to each iteration of array and uses its attribute. The issue is you are querying `checkedBoxes` everytime in the loop.

```
function() {
    var checkedBoxes = $("[name='select-services']:checked");
    checkedBoxes.each(function(index, obj){
        console.log(obj.attr("value"))
    }
```

Comment: The first argument to `each` is the *index*, not the element. Use `this` instead, or use the second argument, not the first.

Comment: Corrected.  The second argument is the value.  I have a healthy disrespect for `this` in javascript and try to avoid it as much as possible.